# How can I keep a button horizontally centered with an input if they have different font sizes?

Tags: css

I have an input box for text and directly next to it is a button.  The problem is when the button font-size and input box font-size is different, the button won't be correctly aligned.

Ex - different font-sizes.  Notice the bottom of the button extends past the input box much more than the top

```css
input{
  font-size:20px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input>
<button class="btn btn-primary m-l">Add</button>
```

Ex: Same font sizes: button is aligned:

```css
input{
  font-size:20px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input>
<button class="btn btn-primary m-l">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but you can achieve this by giving the input a height, and vertically aligning both elements to the middle. See snippet below.

```css
input{
  font-size:20px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<input>
<button class="btn btn-primary m-l">Add</button>
```

Comment: I went with this answer because it doesn't require flex.  Also, I didn't even need to set the height of the input

Answer (score 1):

Use **CSS Flexbox**. And apply `align-items: center` to make your child `<div>`s vertically centered. In my case I've used `body` as my parent element

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
input{
  font-size:20px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<input>
<button class="btn btn-primary m-l">Add</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap your content into a `.container` div and apply `dispaly: flex` to it and that should do the trick for you.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

input{
  font-size:20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input>
  <button class="btn btn-primary m-l">Add</button>
</div>
```

Hope helps (y).

Comment: This is nice, how does this work? Is flex just making all heights within the container the same?